# Vue router doesn't generate the correct link

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm very new in Vue.js and I have to modify an application I didn't write by myself :-/

So I just need to add a link in a vue.

The router is defined like that (excerpt):

```
export default new Router({
routes: [

  ....,
  {
    path: '/client/:idClient',
    component: client,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'sites',
        name: 'client-sites',
        component: clientSites
      },
      .... 
    ]
  },

  .....,
  {
    path: '/onduleur/:idOnduleur',
    name: 'onduleur',
    component: onduleur
  },
  ....
]
})
```

The vue is declared like that:

```
....
        <td><router-link :to="{ name: 'onduleur', params: { idOnduleur: equipement.id }}"> 1 {{ equipement.nom }}</router-link></td>
        <td><router-link :to="{ name: 'client-sites', params: { idClient: equipement.client.idClient }}">{{ equipement.client.raisonSociale }}</router-link></td>
....
```

The first generated link is `http://my_site.com/#/` instead of `http://my_site.com/#/onduleur/12` whereas for the second link I actually have `http://my_site.com/#/client/12/onduleurs`.

According to the [doc](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html), I don't see what prevents the first link to be generated correctly.

Any idea about what I should check?